# Dynamic Query in Mule - Flow variable in SOQL Where Clause

Tags: mule

I am trying to use a flow variable in the where clause of MULE Salesforce connector. But i get an error as below

Query i use

```
#["Select username__c,Group_Name__c from Team_Mapping__c where username__c = " +flowVars.userflowvar]
```

Error:

```
[MalformedQueryFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='MALFORMED_QUERY'
 exceptionMessage='
Team_Mapping__c where username__c = [username@hotmail.com]
                                   ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:74
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code'
]
 row='1'
 column='74'
```

Answer (score 1):

aah i think i found it by myself. it needs to be passed as a string in the where clause.

```
#["Select username__c,Group_Name__c from Team_Mapping__c where username__c = '"+flowVars.userflowvar+"'"]
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @ForceMagic agreed. updated the answer so it could help anyone who come across this issue.

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect! :)

Comment: Can you tell me whey do you use the SOQL instead of the query provided by mule ?

Comment: @NaveenRaj I havent had any requirement to use the MQL till now. But from my knowledge my understanding is if i have to combine data from Salesforce and any local message i might go for MQL. But in my case i was just querying Salesforce so I didnt go for MQL